# What does "Tender on a bid..." mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, terminology

> You have been asked by your manager to tender on a bid to develop [x]
>   for [x].

---

What does "Tender on a bid" mean in this context?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+Tender+on+a+bid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of Tender (on a bid) (via [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tender.asp)):

> To invite bids for a project, or to accept a formal offer such as a takeover bid. Tender usually refers to the process whereby governments and financial institutions invite bids for large projects that must be submitted within a finite deadline. The term also refers to the process whereby shareholders submit their shares or securities to a takeover offer.

Comment: I feel so stupid sometimes, I really did spend some time searching for this, and nothing of the sort appeared in the results. All I got were definitions for the word 'tender' and nothing for the rest of it. Thanks @Ronald.

Comment: It's alright, good to know that I was of some help.

Comment: [Also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_for_bids).

Comment: @RǢF In the future, try limiting your search results by placing word-for-word searches in quotation marks.  'Tender on a bid' will search Google for the words 'tender,' 'on,' 'a,' and 'bid.'  '"Tender on a bid"' will only produce pages with that exact phrase. (Do not type the apostrophes - you get the idea.)